# which takes the text thats is input in the inputbox in html and display it below as a clickable option.

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a project, which takes the text that is input in the inputbox and display it below as a clickable option/button in html. Is it possible to make such thing, if yes please let me know, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: yes, it is possible. Hope that helps

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this what are youre looking for?

```js
function add() {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = document.getElementById("toadd").value;
  document.getElementById("option").add(option);
}
function add2() {
  var aTag = document.createElement("button");
  aTag.setAttribute ("id", Date.now())
  aTag.innerHTML = document.getElementById("toadd").value;;
  document.getElementById("thisdiv").appendChild(aTag);
}
```

```html
<input id="toadd" type="text"/>
<button onClick="add()" >Add</button>
<button onClick="add2()" >Add in another way</button>
<select id="option">
</select>
<div id="thisdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was really useful, and just want to know a thing more that if I want the options to be displayed in serparate lines which are clickable like a button, not inside a select tag than what can i do ?

Comment: Do you mean a simple a tag?

Comment: I added now some lines that adds buttons too.

Comment: Actually i mean to say that what ever I input in the textbox, it get displayed down in the form of button, for eg if i enter "sid" in the textbox and click add, then it makes a button of name "sid" below. Hope you get what I'm trying to say

Comment: Your second code worked great, and it was what i wanted, thankz mate.

Comment: try it now. If you want another tag just replace it or say which one you like. Here is a list of all HTML Tags: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element

Comment: Ok I am glad that i could help you if you want you can accept my answer :)

Comment: hmm i accepted your answer, n thankz again mate. :)

Comment: can u please tell me one more thing, that how will i b able to give a unique ID to each button that have been created dynamically

Comment: depend how unique you need it. But to keeps things siple a timestamp should be enough.

Comment: have a look now.

Comment: ya i want o keep it simple only, can u please tell how should i do that.

Comment: i added this line to the code which sets the id attribute to the current timestamp `aTag.setAttribute ("id", Date.now())`

Comment: I got it, n if i want to call a function by clicking on any dynamically created button than how can I do that. Sorry for troubling you soo much, bt I'm stuck here

Comment: `aTag.setAttribute ("onClick", "functionYouWantToCall()");` It is always the same system.

Comment: thank you soo much

Answer (score 0):

If you want in javascript :

```
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">
<button id='button' style='display:none;'></button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fname");
    document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = x.value
    var x = document.getElementById('button');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
</script>
```

We have 2 elements one is input on which providing any input will appear on the next hidden element (button) `document.getElementById("fname")` will find the element and next line is changing the value of button and then we are making button appear which is hidden till now.
We can also do the very similar thing using jquery

```
<input type="text" id="fname">
<button id='button' style='display:none;'></button>
$( "#fname" ).keyup(function() {
  $("#button").show();
  $("#button").html($(this).val());
})
```

Comment: I'm not able to understand your code sir, here you used variable x for storing two IDs. 1st one was "fname" and another was "button", can you please help me to figure this out

Comment: ok so basically for both the solutions we have one input and one hidden button. which will become visible when you type any text. We have bind keyup event in both scenarios.

Comment: I have updated answer a bit so that it is more clear

Comment: thank mate, now its working